# How to remove two digits after decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a number with two digits after the decimal point; I try to cast this number using `CAST` for example:

```
 Select SUM(CAST((123345.56) as decimal(28, 2))) * 100 AS AMOUNT
```

I get the following result

```
12334556.00
```

but I want get only `12334556` without displaying two digits after the decimal point.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not cast to integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you really want to do, but

```
SELECT SUM(CAST((123345.56 * 100.0) AS DECIMAL(28,0))) AS AMOUNT
```

gives `12334556`.

When you use a number in the format 1234.56 it is a decimal literal in SQL Server: see "decimal constants" in [Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Integer data type is whole numbers, so cast your calculated value as int.

```
Select SUM(CAST((123345.56 * 100) as int)) AS AMOUNT
```